# Access hash of input files in genrule to pass to command in Bazel

Tags: bazel

I am looking for a way run command in genrule with hash of input files.

I want to start replacing Maven with Bazel in my projects. It is a multi-repo setup building selected product from source from different repositories.

```
ProjectA
- moduleA1
- moduleA2

ProjectB
- moduleB1
- moduleB2
```

Maven builds can be executed like this:

```
cd ProjectA
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=A_HASH
mvn clean install 

cd ../ProjectB
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=B_HASH
mvn clean install -DprojectA-version=A_HASH
```

I use `versions:set` to not rely on snapshots and get reliable builds even locally. I could use hash from GIT but it is not enough because 1) I want to have build working locally without committed changed 2) `B_HASH` should change when ProjectA changes

Bazel will let me to re-run maven only when files change but it is not enough to integrate it with maven repository.

Is there a way to implement genrule calling "mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=HASH" with hash of input files? Bazel calculates hash of input files but I cannot find how to expose this hash to genrule.

Answer (score 0):

With Bazel, you can forget about the hacky hash you used with Maven. Bazel maintains hashes for you, and will recompile everything that is needed.
That's the *reliable* part of *{reliable, fast}: Choose two*

Comment: Does this answer mean that it is not supported now and never will be supported? Why is that 'hacky" ? Unique versioning is normal in multi-repo approach - Bazel was implemented for mono-repo so handles such versioning internally but I need to start using bazel step by step and cannot apply approach "all or nothing" - Second top item on bazel [roadmap](https://bazel.build/roadmap.html) is: "**interfacing with external package managers and build systems** The latter is critical for gradual adoption of Bazel."